# Integrate PHP Spout in my project

Tags: php, phpexcel, autoload

I have an old project using a custom autoload class to talk with a MySQL database and PHPExcel:

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    if (stripos($class_name, 'controller') !== false) {
        require_once(System::getPath('CONTROLLERS') . $class_name . '.class.php');
    } else if (stripos($class_name, 'PHPExcel') !== false) {
        $path = System::getPath('EXTERNAL') . str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
        if (is_readable($path)) {
            require_once $path;
        }
    } else {
        if (stripos($class_name, 'abstract') === false) {
            $class_name = str_ireplace('mapper', '', $class_name);
        }
        require_once(System::getPath('MODELS') . $class_name . '.class.php');
    }
}
```

Now I want to migrate my project from PHPExcel to Spout ( https://github.com/box/spout/ ) since PHPExcel is too slow when it has to write big files (30000+ cells with custom styles). If i use the suggested way to integrate Spout in my project by adding

```
require_once System::getPath('EXTERNAL') . '/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';
```

to my file, PHP can no longer find my classes (the one loaded with autoload). Is there any way I can successfully integrate Spout in my project by keeping my custom __autoload function?

Answer (score 0):

The `__autoload` function is a global function that gets overridden when you use the Spout autoloader. To use both autoload functions, you need to switch to [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). It will allow you to define multiple handlers to load your classes (PHP will go through all of them until one can successfully load the class).

So in your case, just replace `function __autoload($class_name)` with `spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name)` and that should work!